# Basically same code but one cause infinite loop in useeffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry, reactjs beginner here, with below two codes, **I don't get why when I use the "First code" I get infinite loop** (infinite log out '123' in my browser console) **and when I use "Second code", I don't get infinite loop** (only log out two '123' in my browser console), **how come I am not getting infinite loop with "Second code" when I am getting infinite loop with my "First code"?**

**(First code) Cause infinite loop:**

```
[Parent.js]
const randomFunc = (dataFromChildComponent) => {
  setData(dataFromChildComponent);
};

[Child.js]
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((post) => {
      randomFunc(post);
      console.log('123');
    });
}, [randomFunc]);
```

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;
const Parent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const randomFunc = (dataFromChildComponent) => {
    setData(dataFromChildComponent);
  };
  
  return <div>
    <p>Parent data: {JSON.stringify(data, null,2)}</p>
    <p>Child: <Child randomFunc={randomFunc} data={data}/></p>;
  </div>
}


const Child = ({randomFunc, data}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((post) => {
        randomFunc(post);
        console.log('123');
      });
  }, [randomFunc]);
  
  return <p>Child data - {JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</p>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**(Second code) Does not cause infinite loop:**

```
[Parent.js]
const randomFunc = (dataFromChildComponent) => {
  setData(dataFromChildComponent);
};

[Child.js]
useEffect(() => {
   randomFunc('Some data!');
   console.log('123');
}, [randomFunc]);
```

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;
const Parent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const randomFunc = (dataFromChildComponent) => {
    setData(dataFromChildComponent);
  };
  
  return <div>
    <p>Parent data: {data}</p>
    <p>Child: <Child randomFunc={randomFunc} data={data}/></p>
  </div>
}


const Child = ({randomFunc, data}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    randomFunc('Some data!');
    console.log('123');
  }, [randomFunc]);
  
  return <p>Child data - {data}</p>
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Three things. First, as state changes, randomFunc in parent is also evaluated again, thus leading to prop in the child component to change and leading to infinite cycle. Second, for the infinite loop to stop, use https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback for `randomFunc` in parent.js. Third, in second case, as the value being set always in `some data!` and doesn't change, it doesn't lead to change in parent's state because if same value is passed state doesn't trigger re-render cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Program:

As state changes `randomFunc` in parent is also evaluated again, thus leading to prop in child component to change and leading to infinite cycle. To stop that from happening you can use https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback for `randomFunc` in `parent.js` like below

```
const randomFunc = useCallback((dataFromChildComponent) => {
  setData(dataFromChildComponent);
}, []);
```

Adding `useCallback` will create a memoized version of the function, which won't change till something in the dependency array doesn't change. In this case as there is no dependency, once it is evaluated it won't change again.

Second Program:

Assuming the `data` state is `null` or `undefined` initially. In the case of second program, the `useEffect` is called because `randomFunc` was initialised once in the beginning. And that would update the parent state `data` to `Some data!`. This would lead to render cycle getting triggered and evaluating `randomFunc` again and thus changing it. This time it would again trigger the `useEffect` in child and tries to update the state in parent component. But as the same value `Some data!` is sent back to the parent state, the parent state ignores that value, thus ending the cycle of rendering again

Comment: Sorry, just to make sure I am totally getting it, so basically with "First code" I need to use useCallback() to create a memoized version of the function to prevent infinite loop, AND with "Second code" I don't need to right? cause, when react found out that the new value I am going to set to data state is the same value as the current one, react won't start a re-render, which will not cause any kind of infinite loop behind the scene, am I correct?

Comment: Cause with "Second code", rather than passing "'Some data!'" back to parent.js in child.js 'useEffect', when I visit child.js page/component,  I am actually going to get the url param(slug) from child.js page/component and pass it back to parent.js using ```randomFunc ``` in child.js ```useEffect```. Example: ```<Route path="/child/:slug" component={Child}/>``` and when I visit the child.js page/component, I am going to get the url param(slug) and do: ```randomFunc(slug)``` in child.js ```useEffect``` to pass the slug back to parent.js to use.

Comment: @JustANewCoder As per your first comment, you understood it correctly. I was not able to understand the second comment. I believe when you speaking about slugs you are using next.js and if that is the case getting details the URL slug in parent component can be done in much more simpler way. You can check useRouter of next.js for that (in case you are using next.js).